# Generating same word over and over again with random on my static list (looping ? )

Tags: c#

I'm making a hangman game and currently when you write down the correct word you get the same number next time, basically it works out like this:

"Hey, figure the word out : 10 letters "

"Correct! figure this word out: 10 letters"

rinse and repeat, even though I have 5 different words in my list at the moment and you can put in your own words.

And does anyone have a clue how to force 1 random word at a time? currently you can guess on every word I have every turn.

Cheers!

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> ordbank  = new List<string>() { "leksak", "djur", "organismer", "mat", "länder" };
    static bool runMenu = true; //kör menyn 
    static bool runGame = false; //kör spelet
    static int numberOfTries = 2; //antal försök personen har på sig 
    static int wrongGuesses = 0; // hur många gånger har personen gissat fel 
    static int numWordsToPutIn = 1; //Lägga till ett extra ord till listan, skulle vilja göra så man kan lägga till fler än 1 åt gången. 


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        var random = new Random();
        int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);
        string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex];
       // För att generera random ord ifrån min ordbank. 

        Console.WriteLine("Hänga gubbe!\n1) Lägg till ord\n2) Lista till alla ord\n3) Spela\n4) Avsluta");
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Menu: ");
            string menuInput = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (menuInput.ToLower())
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Du ska lägga till " + numWordsToPutIn + " ord nu.");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numWordsToPutIn; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till ord " + i + ": ");
                        string wordInput = Console.ReadLine();
                        ordbank.Add(wordInput);

                    }
                    ordbank.Sort();
                    break;  //Ifall man vill lägga till nytt ord till listan.

                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Nu skrivs alla orden ut: ");
                    if (ordbank.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (string ord in ordbank)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ord);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Listan är tom. Fyll den först."); //Behövs denna nu när jag ändrade så ord redan finns?
                    }
                    break; //Skriver ut orden de lagt in + orden som redan finns.

                case "3":
                    if (ordbank.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Fyll ordlistan med " + numWordsToPutIn + " ord innan du börjar spelet");
                        break;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många fel får man ha: " + numberOfTries + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Då kör vi, gissa ordet : " + randomWord.Length + " Bokstäver "); //Length kollar antal bokstäver     
                    runGame = true;
                    wrongGuesses = 0; 
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Write("Gissa ord: ");
                        string guessedWord = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (ordbank.Contains(guessedWord))
                        {
                            ordbank.Remove(guessedWord);


                            //kolla om personen har vunnit 
                            if (ordbank.Count == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Grattis du vann");
                                runGame = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Wohoo det ordet fanns med, Gissa ordet: " + randomWord.Length + " Bokstäver "); //Length kollar antal bokstäver
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wrongGuesses++;
                            //kolla om personen har förlorat 
                            if (wrongGuesses == numberOfTries)
                            {
                                runGame = false;
                                Console.WriteLine("Du förlorade.");
                                ordbank.Clear();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Du gissade fel, du har " + (numberOfTries - wrongGuesses) + " försök kvar");
                            }
                        }

                    } while (runGame);
                    break;

                case "4":
                    Console.WriteLine("Spelet avslutas nu...");
                    runMenu = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Snälla välj ett tal mellan 1 - 4.");
                    break;        
            }
        } while (runMenu == true);

    }
}
```

Edit 2:

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> ordbank  = new List<string>() { "leksak", "djur", "organismer", "mat", "länder" };
    static bool runMenu = true; //kör menyn 
    static bool runGame = false; //kör spelet
    static int numberOfTries = 2; //antal försök personen har på sig 
    static int wrongGuesses = 0; // hur många gånger har personen gissat fel 
    static int numWordsToPutIn = 1; //Lägga till ett extra ord till listan, skulle vilja göra så man kan lägga till fler än 1 åt gången. 


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        var random = new Random();
        //int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);
        //string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex]; 
        // För att generera random ord ifrån min ordbank. 

        Console.WriteLine("Hänga gubbe!\n1) Lägg till ord\n2) Lista till alla ord\n3) Spela\n4) Avsluta");
        do
        {
            int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);
            string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex]; 

            Console.Write("Menu: ");
            string menuInput = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (menuInput.ToLower())
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Du ska lägga till " + numWordsToPutIn + " ord nu.");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numWordsToPutIn; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till ord " + i + ": ");
                        string wordInput = Console.ReadLine();
                        ordbank.Add(wordInput);

                    }
                    ordbank.Sort();
                    break;  //Ifall man vill lägga till nytt ord till listan.

                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Nu skrivs alla orden ut: ");
                    if (ordbank.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (string ord in ordbank)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ord);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Listan är tom. Fyll den först."); //Behövs denna nu när jag ändrade så ord redan finns?
                    }
                    break; //Skriver ut orden de lagt in + orden som redan finns.

                case "3":
                    if (ordbank.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Fyll ordlistan med " + numWordsToPutIn + " ord innan du börjar spelet");
                        break;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Hur många fel får man ha: " + numberOfTries + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Då kör vi, gissa ordet : " + randomWord.Length + " Bokstäver "); //Length kollar antal bokstäver     
                    runGame = true;
                    wrongGuesses = 0; 
                   do

                    {
                        Console.Write("Gissa ord: ");
                        string guessedWord = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (ordbank.Contains(guessedWord))
                        {
                            ordbank.Remove(guessedWord);


                            //kolla om personen har vunnit 
                            if (ordbank.Count == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Grattis du vann");
                                runGame = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Wohoo det ordet fanns med, Gissa ordet: " + randomWord.Length + " Bokstäver "); //Length kollar antal bokstäver
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wrongGuesses++;
                            //kolla om personen har förlorat 
                            if (wrongGuesses == numberOfTries)
                            {
                                runGame = false;
                                Console.WriteLine("Du förlorade.");
                                ordbank.Clear();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Du gissade fel, du har " + (numberOfTries - wrongGuesses) + " försök kvar");
                            }
                        }

                    } while (runGame);
                    break;

                case "4":
                    Console.WriteLine("Spelet avslutas nu...");
                    runMenu = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Snälla välj ett tal mellan 1 - 4.");
                    break;        
            }
        } while (runMenu == true);

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have `random.Next` at exactly one place in your program, and it isn't inside a loop. You're generating a random number with an upper value of `ordbank.Count`, and picking a random word using it, exactly once. Presumably you'll get a new value the next time you run the program.

Comment: Maybe you want to move the second and third statements inside `Main` into the `do` loop you have?

Comment: Why does it say the same amount each turn? I answer all the guesses correct and every turn it says "10 letters" or whatever the amount it decide to say for that game.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on how your program is supposed to work or what each of the case branches are supposed to do, since I can't read Swedish. However, I do know that there is exactly one number generated randomly per run of your program, right at the beginning of `Main`. During a given program run, you're only displaying the length of one word over and over again, the one you chose right at the beginning.

Comment: Basically the program is suppost to work the following: "Hey guess the word: it has 10 letters"  then you guess, if you guess correct you get a new word, but when this happens they get the same number as the last word.

Comment: Could you please try moving the second and third line inside `Main` into the `do` block?

Comment: Which lines do you mean? int.random lines?

Comment: @ztupman Yes, that is because you're displaying `randomWord.Length`, and `randomWord` never changes between iterations of your `do` loop. You pick it at the beginning of the program and never change it inside the loop.

Comment: `int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);` and `string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex];`. Move these inside the `do` loop.

Comment: Doesn't work,"embedded statement" and "invalid string"

Comment: Are these compiler errors that you're getting? Did you move the statements correctly?

Comment: Sorry, made it work now with where to put it, the same problem still remains though.

Comment: Your code is still broken, but I'm pretty sure you don't have the same problem. Once you guess an item, the number should change now.

Comment: Could you update your code to show what you have now?

Comment: There we go, edited the post

Comment: I missed the fact that you had an inner loop as well. You need to generate in there, not in the outer do loop.

Comment: But then my randomWord at case 3 won't work. because it's above the                     int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);
string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex];

Comment: Keep the `int randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);` and `string randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex];` where you originally had them, put `randomIndex = random.Next(ordbank.Count);` and `randomWord = ordbank[randomIndex]` inside your inner do loop. I would be able to fix your code all at once if you translated to English or provided English comments. As things stand I have to basically guess what's happening in each branch.